# How to center main content ignoring navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a login form using Bootstrap Sign-in example page, but want to add a navbar on top. If I add the navbar, it moves the main content a bit to the bottom, so it's not centered perfectly, but centered if we measure from navbar to the bottom. I want to center the form ignoring the navbar. How do I do that?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">
  <head><script src="{% static 'js/color-modes.js' %}"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.115.4">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}">

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sign-in/">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/css@3">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/sign-in.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/cover.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex align-items-center py-4 bg-body-tertiary">

    <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column justify-content-center">
      <header class="mb-auto">
        <div>
          <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0">Music Scholars</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Contact</a>
            <div class="px-0 dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link fw-bold" style="padding: 0.25rem 0 0.25rem 0!important; margin-left: 1rem;" href="#" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Tim <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              </a>
            
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Results</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto justify-content-md-center">
        <form>
          <div class="login-logo">
            <img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'images/bootstrap-logo.svg' %}" alt="" width="72" height="57">
          </div>
          <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please log in</h1>
      
          <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingLoginPassword" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="floatingLoginPassword">Password</label>
          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-body-secondary">Don't have an account yet? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Create one</a></p>
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```